# Is there a way to find out last restart time for all EC2 instances using Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to get how long every ec2 instances are running for 'running' instances. For this I need to get last restart time for all instances and compare that with today. Found that I can get restart or start event from cloudtrail but can't figure out how to get only 'start' time from there. Is there a way to find that information for a couple of regions?

```
import boto3
import datetime
from datetime import date
import subprocess


regions = ['us-west-2', 'us-west-1', 'us-east-1','us-east-2','ap-south-1', 'ap-southeast-1','ca-central-1','eu-west-1','eu-west-3']


    for region in regions:
        session = boto3.session.Session(region_name=region)
        ec2 = session.resource('ec2')
        cloudtrail = boto3.client('cloudtrail')

        for i in ec2.instances.all():
            Id = i.id
            State = i.state['Name']
            Launchtime = i.launch_time
            InstanceType = i.instance_type
            Platform = str(i.platform)
            currenttime = datetime.datetime.now(Launchtime.tzinfo)
            time_diff = currenttime - Launchtime
            uptime = str(time_diff)
```

Here uptime is giving time difference between launch time and current time, which is not correct as most of the instances been restarted lot of time already. So I need to find last start time for all running instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tweaked my code little bit and made like this:

```
import boto3
import datetime
from datetime import date
import subprocess


regions = ['us-west-2', 'us-west-1', 'us-east-1']


    for region in regions:
        session = boto3.session.Session(region_name=region)
        ec2 = session.resource('ec2')

        for i in ec2.instances.all():
            Id = i.id
            State = i.state['Name']
            Launchtime = i.launch_time
            InstanceType = i.instance_type
            Platform = str(i.platform)
            currenttime = datetime.datetime.now(Launchtime.tzinfo)
            time_diff = currenttime - Launchtime
            uptime = str(time_diff)
            if i.state['Name'] == 'stopped':
                uptime = ' '
```

Here it's showing uptime for only running instances. Found out Launch time is showing as last time these instances started (Launched). Cross checked in console and those were right. Then checked up time for the Linux instances (`sudo uptime`) and those matched with output.